# Find <tr> that contains a known selector

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I want to get the `<tr>` element of a table by knowing the ID of one of it's elements (div).

Here's what the table looks like in HTML:

```
<table id="table-0">
  <thead>
  <tr role="row">
   <th>house</th>
   <th>phone</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr class="odd">
  <td class="">
    <div id="56"></div>my house
  </td>
  <td class="">
    <div id="57"></div>1234
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So I would like to get the `<tr>` element that has a `<td>` element that contains a `<div>` with the ID 56 (in this example).

Here's what I tried in jQuery (data['id'] = 56):

```
 var tr = $("tr:has(td:has($(\"#\" + data['id']))))");
```

Comment: An ID shouldn't start with a number, and should be unique.

Comment: You have two elements with the same `id` - this is invalid in HTML. You need to use classes for grouped identifiers.

Comment: @adeneo in HTML5 an `id` attribute beginning with a number is valid

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - that's true, my bad. -> `$('#56').closest('tr')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also find the tr by element Id :

```
var tr = $('#Id').closest("tr");
```

In your case :

```
var tr = $('#56').closest("tr");
```

Comment: This way the guy will still use a Duplicated ID on the HTML, this is incorrect for HTML Standards.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tr = $("tr:has('#" + data['id'] + "')");
```

**N.B.:** Check that all your elements in a single page have unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
var tr = $('tr:has("td div#"'+data['id']+')');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your output with below jQuery expression

```
$('tr').find('#56').closest('tr')
```

And also remember ID assigned to `HTML` controls should unique throughout page.

With above expression you will get `tr` object (i.e. whole tr with controls of id specified)

Answer (score 0):

**First: is totally invalid to use same ID to more of one element because the ID is Unique. Its a HTML Standard.**

But if you want to get the selector for your element you can use this (**without needing ID**):

```
$('tr.odd').children().children();
```

**This is the correct way because you dont need a Duplicated ID.**